# Pi Pico W as RNDIS USB Tethering WIFI Dongle

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico

We have built a [Pi Pico W based RNDIS USB tethering Wifi Dongle](https://github.com/sidd-kishan/PicoPiFi) the Upload Speed is **8Mbps** but the download speed is **3Mbps** at max. Please help us improve the download speed, following is the code snippet used for wifi to eth:-

```c
void cyw43_cb_process_ethernet(void *cb_data, int itf, size_t len, const uint8_t *buf) {if (len <= 1500) {
    struct pbuf *out_pkt = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_RAW, len, PBUF_POOL);
    pbuf_take(out_pkt, buf, len);
    usbd_rndis_eth_tx(out_pkt);
}}
```